# Developing 2D in 3D with orthographic projection and stretched model

Tags: graphics, xna

I was wondering if there is any benefit to using an orthographic projection camera, to make a 2D game with 3D models (as opposed to making sprites and using 2D).

Also, on a related note when I use orthographic projection, my 3d-model is stretched. Does anyone know why this is happening? I know that aspect ratio only influences the perspective projection, so this should not be happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you developing a 2D game, using 3D models would be a lot of pointless overhead - both for you as the developer and for the system running the game. Even if you have fancy 3D models and are not very good at drawing sprites you could still use a 3D modeling tool to project the models to images.

Comment: You were right. I am doing 2d now and I am getting miles ahead of where I was when I was doing 3d. I will graduate to 3d eventually (if i keep this up), but for faster dev time 2d certainly is a speedup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a 2d game, ortho with 3d models might be better, because you can take advantage of hardware acceleration with OpenGL and Direct3D. However, sprites are much easier to make than 3d models.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking 2d functions can also take advantage of hardware accelaration.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but often 2D graphics libraries don't use acceleration, or use the driver's 2D acceleration. With most graphics drivers, 2D operations using 3D are faster that 2D.